# UITableViewCell's drag control sensitivity in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Does anyone have any tips on reducing the sensitivity of the drag handle on UITableViewCell?

I'm doing something a little custom where I find the drag handle view from the UITableViewCell and give it the frame of the entire cell so you can touch anywhere to drag. In iOS 6 the sensitivity of the view was moderate such that it didn't interfere with scrolling gestures. Now in iOS 7 they've made it so responsive that it's near impossible to scroll the UITableView parent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your easiest solution for iOS 7 is to not do that. I don’t know of API to affect it, though if you’re already doing something custom with the grabber view then you might see if there’s a gesture recognizer attached to it that you can mess with.

Comment: Yeah I did a bit of snooping on the class and it's a UIControl subclass with no gestures attached unfortunately. I've tried playing around with UIControl's `- (void)cancelTrackingWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event` but it's not working that well.